# How do I automatically generate a tags file with ripper-tags for ruby?

Tags: tags

How do I get [ripper-tags](https://github.com/tmm1/ripper-tags) to automatically generate a `tags` file for my ruby buffers upon save?

Comment: Is this a question related to Vim? I'm sensing that your question is not. But maybe you could explicit what you need and how it relates to Vim.

Comment: I edited the question to show how what I want to do interacts with `vim`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I don't have ripper-tags installed, this is my best guess on browsing the documentation.

In the documentation it says that the typical usage is:

```
ripper-tags -R --exclude=vendor
```

> This parses all `*.rb` files in the current project, excluding ones in `vendor/` directory, and saves tags in Vim format to a file named `./tags`.

Using this with an autocmd on save I would get something like the following:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.rb !ripper-tags -R --exclude=vendor
```

- `autocmd BufWritePost` Sets up an auto command to do something everytime we write to a file
- `*.rb` Only execute on ruby files (.rb extension)
- `!...` Executes following command in a shell

Put this line in your `vimrc` file to enable the auto command.

See `:h BufWritePost` and `:h !` for more info.